# Set the background-image values of all divs of a specific class based on ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, background-image

I'd like to write a script that automatically sets the background-image url of all the divs on my page with the classes .img-cover based on the value of each ones 'data-image' attribute. This way whenever I want to set a background-image I can simply add the correct 'data-image' value and class to a div and it will automatically pull the correct image.

**UPDATE**

CSS doesn't seem to like having periods in ids, so I removed the '.jpg' from all the IDs and added it to the script, and swapped out a data attribute for the ids. Here's the html:

```
<div class="img-cover" data-image="flags_install"></div>
```

the new jquery:

```
$(".img-cover").each(function() {
        var data = $(this).attr('data-image');
        console.log(data);
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('/img/cover-imgs/" + data + ".jpg');");
        console.log($(this).css("background-image"));
    });
```

I also added console logs and am getting the data values from the first one but it's just returning "none" for the background-image one still. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the naming convention "id="flags_install.jpg" I think .jpg is parsed as another class applied to the element.

Try approaching it via id="flags_install" and then 
$(this).css("background-image", "url('/img/cover-imgs/" + id + ".jpg');");

**Working:**

$(this).css('background-image', 'url(/img/cover-imgs/' + data + '.jpg)');

Comment: Just fixed this and updated the question a moment ago, this was definitely also an issue as well but there seems to still be another problem.

Comment: $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/img/cover-imgs/' + data + '.jpg)'); mixing " and ' does not always work consistent

Comment: Aha! It was the semicolon inside the quotes after '.jpg)', the jQuery css method doesn't need this, it's only a part of CSS syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).css("background-image", "url('/img/cover-imgs/'" + id + ");");
//                                                    ^ there's your problem
```

That apostrophe is resulting in

```
/img/cover-imgs/'some-img.jpg
```

Should be

```
$(this).css("background-image", "url('/img/cover-imgs/" + id + "');");
```

Incidentally, IDs probably aren't the best fit for this. Sure it'll work, but in the spirit with which attributes are intended for certain purposes, a data attribute would be a better fit.

Comment: Yeah I caught that right after I posted and moved the '. Still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Good find! I also agree about the ID's, I think using a dataset would be a better approach. `data-image="*****"`

Comment: @Will - there's no reason that wouldn't work provided the image paths are correct. Do some debugging in dev tools. Does the background image get set? Perhaps the style gets set but it can't find the image? Etc. Failing all else, set up a Fiddle.

Comment: @Utkanos I've messed with the css some but when i inspect it the background-image doesn't get set anyway, so still stuck on that.

Comment: Check the JS runs at all. Console? Running before the DOM is ready? Does the `each` iteration callback fire? (Put an alert inside it.) Etc.

Comment: As suggested by **Utkanos**, try some debugging... maybe `console.log($(this).css('background-image'));` to check? I would suggest you double check the path of those images too.

Comment: @NewToJS I checked the paths and ran console.logs on both lines, the data variable returns as expected but the css change doesn't, it returns as "none". Also the image paths work, I tried directly adding the background-image with an id selector in CSS and it showed up.

Comment: Then you'll need to try to reproduce this in a Fiddle and link it here so we can see.